# XML Horizontal and Vertical LinearLayout with Automatically

Tags: xml, android-linearlayout, horizontal-line

I created a horizontal LinearLayout. And I added couple of TextViews. The problem is, the width isn't enough for this,thats why last TextViews didn't seem. I want it to look like the image below. Is there anyway to do this with XML codes. Thank you for helping.

Which Layer should I use ? Or How can I do like image below.

[image: This is the image of what I want to do.]

I started with these xml codes.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lyShf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/widget71"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/st_25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/st_10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txShf1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_frame_bej"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:text="sample"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txShf3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_frame_bej"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:text="sample"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txShf4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_frame_bej"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:text="sample"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txShf5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_frame_bej"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:text="sample"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txShf6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_frame_bej"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:text="sample"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txShf7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/layout_frame_bej"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="@dimen/st_5dp"
        android:text="sample"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

---

**Solved: I found the solution by FlexboxLayout. You can look at this link for detail.**

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/02/build-flexible-layouts-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Try using [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). Put the TextView as item child for GirdView.

Comment: Sorry Santhosh, But I didn't again. I added new image to my question.

Comment: No problem Santhosh. Thank you.